# Drawing UIImage on CGContext doesn't show up

Tags: ios, swift, cgcontext

I'm having a custom NSLayoutManager and I want to draw a blurred rectangle over a word. I'm trying just to draw a red rectangle right now and it doesn't draw anything. I need to do this in an image because on the image you can apply gaussianblur. The image is not nil so that's not the problem.

Drawing code

```
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(blurRect.size);
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: blurRect.size)
    let image = renderer.image { ctx in
        ctx.cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        ctx.cgContext.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
        ctx.cgContext.setLineWidth(10)
        ctx.cgContext.addRect(blurRect)
        ctx.cgContext.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    image.draw(in: blurRect)
    context.draw(image.cgImage!, in: blurRect)
```

I call this code in this method:

```
override func drawGlyphs(forGlyphRange glyphsToShow: NSRange, at origin: CGPoint) {
```